# Is I2C clock continuous or does it depend on acknowledge from DUT?

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-uno

Below is the I2C waveform obtained from my DUT. Blue is the SDA and red is the clock waveform.

You can see that two acknowledgements are coming (yellow circle).

After that you can see that there is no ACK and SDA pulled to LOW and SCL pulled to high.

No clock is coming after that. Is this expected behaviour? I mean, the clock properly comes from the Arduino when it receives an ACK properly.

[image]

Below wave from is captured when read is happening properly from DUT.This read is also not consistent.
[image]

Shcematic is given below.

[image]

The clock to the DUT is not directly given from Arduino.We are using a circuit called voltage modulator.This modulator is designed using a SPDT switch.One I/P of the switch is connected to
3.8V and another I/P is connected to 2.9V.The clock coming from Arduino is used as a control signal for this SPDT switch.If CLK is high output will be 3.8V and when it is low the output will be 2.9V.

This 2.9V and 3.8V is coming from a Power analyzer(Key sight N6705C).The 2.9V is also connected to VREF_LOW of the level shifter.
The modulator circuit is given below.

[image]

Comment: The clock waveform seems to have some problem. Can you explain why it does not go to 0V like SDA does, and can you explain why it looks like being driven as push-pull output, unlike the yellow trace which looks about correct for SCL?

Comment: If you don't mind could you please read the last two paragraphs of my question. The clock is generated in a different way it will swing from 2.8v to 3.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SCL is under the control of the controller (previously called "master") device except that the target (previously called "slave") device may do clock stretching by holding SCL low. The controller should be generating SCL continuously between START condition and STOP condition (except that it is completely asynchronous and the high and low durations may vary considerably).

Since SCL is stopping high, we know the target is not clock stretching. Therefore the clock is still under control of the controller.

Looking closely at your trace, it appears that SDA is transitioning low-to-high while SCL is low. This appears to be the controller sending the STOP condition, in the middle of a frame. This is legal but may be confusing the state machine in the target device.

Actually the fact that the ACKs from the target device are pulling down only to ~0.8 volts (instead of zero) gives us a clue. Since the low SDA at the end is also at ~0.8 volts, it's pretty clear that the target is the one holding SDA low.

There is also an abnormality that the ACK seems to be holding longer than expected, all the way to the next SCL going low.

I'm assuming that your controller is writing to the target and the target is ACKing.

<del>I don't like that the ACK is only going down to ~0.8 volts. It could be that the pull-up is too strong for the target. It could also be that the controller is pulling-up instead of going high-Z when idle. Reading from your question that you're using an Arduino for the controller, are you somehow programming you SCL pin as push-pull instead of open-drain?</del>

I see now that you're using a voltage translator on SDA. That explains the difference in LOW voltage.

I'm guessing that the DUT is the target device and you've exposed a bug in its state machine.

I'm guessing that the target is the DUT

Comment: ,Thank you.Very informative.I added some more details in the Question.If you don't mind could you please check.

Comment: @HARITO I now understand LOW voltage difference. It still looks like the Arduino is sending one bit followed by a STOP and that (or something) is confusing your DUT.

Comment: "Arduino is sending one bit followed by a STOP" is this due to an errror in the code

Comment: @HARITO The DUT is still responding poorly (locking up SDA) to that error condition. For reliability's sake, that should also be fixed. Your code bug was lucky to expose tis bug.

Comment: "ACK is only going down to ~0.8 volts" is this due to the level shifter